# While loop never ending message

Tags: c++, while-loop

I want to test the input if it is `double` but the message that I wrote to pop up if the input is not `double` never stops to show up. Although when I turn the double into string everything its OK. Please help. I can't figure out what I have to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    double x;
    cout<<"Enter Number.\n";
    while (!(cin>>x)){
        cout<<"please only numbers.\n";
        cin >>x;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If an input operation fails, each subsequent one fails until you reset the flag. You probably want to discard the problematic input as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `cin.ignore(1000, '\n');` to clear the input. You will also need to use `cin.clear();` to remove the "failed" bit, so that the next input can succeed.